# How to manage passwords in scripts

Tags: r, security

I often write scripts which I put on Github. As much as I want to share my code, there are certain things such as passwords which I do not want share. Often my code would look something like this:

```
myapp <- oauth_app("app_name", "long_complicated_sha_code")
github_token <- oauth2.0_token(oauth_endpoints("github"), myapp) 
gtoken <- config(token = github_token)
req <- GET("https://api.github.com/rate_limit", gtoken)
```

What is a better way to manage usernames and passwords in scripts? I want to make the code as reproducible as possible, easy for myself to run, without sharing my usernames and passwords with the world.

Comment: Use environment variables for the usernames/passwords.

Comment: @Buddy: Can you explain a bit more - I cannot understand.

Comment: Store your username & password as environment variables.. and then you can access them via your R script like: `sha_code <- Sys.getenv("SECRET_SHA_CODE")`

Comment: @Buddy: can you give an example of how I store usrname/pass as environment variables?

Comment: Try the [secure](https://github.com/hadley/secure) package.